# Problem to run Ionic/Angular app in Android Studio (io.fabric not found)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have an error in Android Studio, when i try to run my `Ionic/Angular` app, i got an error "`ERROR: Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found.`"

I already copied the `config.json` file from Firebase (Crashlytics) and tried to change the dependencies as many tutorials said, but nothing is working fine cuz i got another error related to Manifest merged failed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGTNG.png).
I seems to be a problem with `capacitor cordova plugin`. Please someone who can show me some light at the end of this tunnel.
[enter image description here][2]